# IE10 dropdown menus not resizing properly when page-zooming

Tags: windows-7, windows, java, internet-explorer-10

Drop-down menus are not displaying right in IE 10 when using anything other than 100% zoom.

100%:

[image]

125%:

[image]

75%:

[image]

It is working on one computer, but I can't identify the difference.

Both computers are running the latest version of Java. The one where it works is also running Java 6 Update 27 (64-bit) and Java Update 30, but installing these on the other computer was no help. I'd like to add that it worked on the one computer because of a user account. That user account works on other computers. It is an admin account, but the only admin account that works.

Any ideas why this would be happening?

Have tried:

- Running IE in compatibility mode
- Resetting IE

My thoughts are that this still might have something to do with Java, but I'm not sure what to do about it. Switching to a different browser/IE version is not an option.

Comment: Hi there, I rolled back to the previous edit. Posting pictures that are small like this are definitely acceptable, and it also corrects some of the terms used in Internet Explorer. Hopefully this helps

Comment: Thanks. I edited something else, and it overrode the other edit. Don't know why. First time, I used this forum.

Comment: It's 'Compatibility', not 'Comparability' mode, and Java needs a capital J at the start. As well, it's more readable this way, especially since the third link was broken in your edit. That's why I rolled it back.

Comment: yeah, typo thanks. Someone put in an answer before and I replied to it and now it is gone. Do they get deleted if they don't solve the problem or did the user simply retract it?

Comment: The user (me) retracted it, since it didn't help. It should have probably been a comment. Hopefully someone else has a bit more knowledge, and can help you out though.

Comment: I'd like to add that it worked on the one computer because of a user account. That user account works on other computers. It is an admin account, but the only admin account that works.